# Printing a Sudoku Matrix in Java- How to get output to the correct format

Tags: java

This will probably be a very easy and a "oh my god, it is so obivous!" question but given a sudoku matrix using code this like:

```
sudoku = new int[9][9];

public void printBoard() 
{
   for (int i=0; i<9; i++){
       for (int j=0; j<9; j++){
       if (sudoku[i][j] == 0) System.out.print(". "); 
       if (sudoku[i][j] == 1) System.out.print("1 ");
               if (sudoku[i][j] == 2) System.out.print("2 ");
               if (sudoku[i][j] == 3) System.out.print("3 ");
               if (sudoku[i][j] == 4) System.out.print("4 ");
               if (sudoku[i][j] == 5) System.out.print("5 ");
               if (sudoku[i][j] == 6) System.out.print("6 ");
               if (sudoku[i][j] == 7) System.out.print("7 ");
               if (sudoku[i][j] == 8) System.out.print("8 ");
               if (sudoku[i][j] == 9) System.out.print("9 ");
       }
       System.out.println(" ");
   }
```

}

What am I missing to get output like this:

```
. . .   9 . 2   6 . 4
6 . 4   3 . .   . 7 .
. 7 .   1 . 4   . . .

. . 3   . 1 9   8 . .
1 5 .   . 4 .   . 9 7
. . 7   8 2 .   3 . .

. . .   2 . 6   . 5 .
. 3 .   . . 7   1 . 2
9 . 2   5 . 1   . . .
```

Like I said, I know I'm missing a few lines of code to make this happen, but I'd appreciate any help!  Thanks!

Comment: What does it print right now?

Comment: Do you assign ints to the array at any point?

Comment: the array is empty lol

Comment: @RobertoNicbaAnićBanić Thats what I am thinking

Comment: I know it is empty, I'm just working on the output first

Comment: yeah he needs an algorithm for sudoku thats complex

Comment: Note: `int val = sodoku[i][j]; System.out.printf("%s ", val == 0 ? '.' : val);` If you want to avoid a lot of `if` statements.

Comment: @ColeJacobWandler look at my answer now it does what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need to do:

```
package hts;


public class HTS {

static int[][] sudoku = new int[9][9];

public static void printBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            System.out.print("\n");
            if(i%3==0)
                System.out.print("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (j % 3 == 0)
                System.out.print(" ");
            if (sudoku[i][j] == 0)
                System.out.print(". ");
            if (sudoku[i][j] == 1)
                System.out.print("1 ");
            if (sudoku[i][j] == 2)
                System.out.print("2 ");
            if (sudoku[i][j] == 3)
                System.out.print("3 ");
            if (sudoku[i][j] == 4)
                System.out.print("4 ");
            if (sudoku[i][j] == 5)
                System.out.print("5 ");
            if (sudoku[i][j] == 6)
                System.out.print("6 ");
            if (sudoku[i][j] == 7)
                System.out.print("7 ");
            if (sudoku[i][j] == 8)
                System.out.print("8 ");
            if (sudoku[i][j] == 9)
                System.out.print("9 ");
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printBoard();
}

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
. . .  . . .  . . . 
. . .  . . .  . . . 
. . .  . . .  . . . 

. . .  . . .  . . . 
. . .  . . .  . . . 
. . .  . . .  . . . 

. . .  . . .  . . . 
. . .  . . .  . . . 
. . .  . . .  . . .
```

Comment: Note: `int val = sodoku[i][j]; System.out.printf("%s ", val == 0 ? '.' : val);` If you want to avoid a lot of if statements.

Comment: You really should edit your first answer rather than composing a brand new answer

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a lot points `.`, because the element in the array have all the value `0` (by default). Therefore because of the condition:

```
if (sudoku[i][j] == 0) System.out.print(". ");
```

you will get only points.

**Edit:** to print in the desired format, you could try checking if `i` and `j` values are multiple of 3:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0 && i != 0) // not first iteration
        System.out.println(); // print extra new-line each 3 iterations

    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        if (j % 3 == 0) 
            System.out.print(" "); // to print spaces between columns

        if (sudoku[i][j] == 0) {
            System.out.print(". ");
            continue; // since it's 0, continue with next iteration
        }
        ... // here print values
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Output:**

```
 . . .  . . .  . . . 
 . . .  . . .  . . . 
 . . .  . . .  . . . 

 . . .  . . .  . . . 
 . . .  . . .  . . . 
 . . .  . . .  . . . 

 . . .  . . .  . . . 
 . . .  . . .  . . . 
 . . .  . . .  . . .
```

Comment: I don't think he's concerned with the values being printed, just the format of the output.